# How Can I Filter Out Sessions to This URI?

Tags: google-analytics

This is probably a complete newbie question (ok, it is a newbie question).

I created a view for my site to just show members who have not registered yet. This is pretty easy to do as non-members visit the site at www.* and members visit at app.*

However, I want to filter out sessions from users who visit www.*.com/login/

I've set a filter to exclude the request URL of /login/, but when I check the real time reports I still see sessions on this URI.

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter excluding all [URL request](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034380?hl=en) with **/login/** subfolder. That should be the last filter of the view ([order matters](http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/google-analytics-filter-order-matters/))

[image]